Omit subsection numbering in subsubsections
I want a numbering scheme like this

1 Name of first section
1.1 Name of first subsection
Theorem 1.1
Lemma 1.2
Theorem 1.3
1.2 Name of second subsection
Definition 1.4
Theorem 1.5
2 Name of second section
Theorem 2.1

At the moment I'm using subsubsections for my theorems, definitions, etc. and I need the numbering on them to be compatible with \label and \ref. However by default they show like this

1 Name of first section
1.1 Name of first subsection
1.1.1 Theorem
1.1.2 Lemma
1.1.3 Theorem
1.2 Name of second subsection
1.2.1 Definition
1.2.2 Theorem
2 Name of second section
Theorem 2.0.1

Any way to have it behave like the first variant above? My documentclass is article.

I can reproduce your output with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} % recommended

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Name of first section}

\subsection{Name of first subsection}

\begin{theorem}
Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
Text of the lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Name of second subsection}

\begin{definition}
Text of the definition
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{Name of second section}

\begin{theorem}
Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


You just need to change [subsection] into [section]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} % recommended

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % <---- CHANGE HERE
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Name of first section}

\subsection{Name of first subsection}

\begin{theorem}
Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
Text of the lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Name of second subsection}

\begin{definition}
Text of the definition
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{Name of second section}

\begin{theorem}
Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


